# Having free time [grammar]

Tags: sentence-construction

I tried to make a sentence:

> The job I'm working at doesn't give me a chance to solve sophisticated
>   problems and I have too much free time there.

To me, the subclause **I have too much free time there** doesn't sound naturally (especially **there** at the end of the sentence). In fact, I tried to express that the job is simple and I have too much free time. Is my sentence correct? If not, how could I remake it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use *so* since the second clause is a result of the first one:

> The job I'm working at doesn't give me a chance to solve sophisticated problems, **so** I have too much free time.

*there* is not part of any other phrase, and by itself only serves to point back to the job (location). "there" might be OK if "job" and "job location" are not the same. Or if you need some emphasis in context.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what did you mean by __there is hanging there by itself__. Coudln't you expand it for a little?

Comment: I edited my answer so hopefully it is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds correct to me, but you could say "when i'm there I have to much free time."